# Force Applications to use Teracopy

Tags: windows-7, 7-zip, teracopy

I use Teracopy **everywhere**

I really like it and have found it to be stabler/faster/better than vanilla copy.

However when using certain applications, namely 7zip for one, (I am certain there are more, but haven't discovered them yet) it uses the standard windows copy.

This happens when I click&drag an file out of an opened archive window to a folder.

My question is: Can I force any application to use Teracopy instead of Windows-Copy.

I know that the Teracopy install overwrites the default copy/move handlers in windows, but it seems like 7zip ignores this.

Comment: What you want is not possible.  These applications were written a certain way, you would have to replace the default copy feature with Teracopy, and I don't believe that to be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teracopy allows you to set it as the default COPY/MOVE handler for windows operations, but the WRITE operation you're using as an example isn't handled at the level Teracopy works at.

Basically, if you click on a windows file/folder icon, and indicate to windows you want to copy or  move it, then Teracopy will kick in.

For 7zip (for example), the file display you see is a representation of what's in the archive file... clicking and dragging (or cut&paste) invokes a write operation from the archive, through the unzipper function which expands it to normal size and then writes it to the disk in the place you specified (or clicked, dragged, etc).

Basically, Windows to Windows will invoke Teracopy, program to Windows or Windows to program, likely not, since they don't expose a mechanism where Teracopy could attach and intercede.

Comment: 7zip extracts the files to a %AppData&\Loca\Temp folder and then uses the Windows move handler to relocate them to their final destination. It's for this "last-leg" of the journey that 7zip should be using the chosen copy handler (and does) but it breaks because 7zip aggressively culls the temporary files before TeraCopy can access them.